# HDD spins down and back up with a 'click' sound when screen is off

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

Background:

- laptop: Acer Aspire A515-51G
- HDD: WDC WD10SPZX-21Z10T0 (WD-WXK1A670LNDT) (1TB) - Secondary storage device
- OS: Windows 10
- SMART values:

  [image: SMART values]

Issue:

My HDD is spinning down and back up with a 'click' sound every time my screen turns off and I don't know what to make of it because of its weird occurrence. The whole process lasts around 2 seconds and repeats itself until the screen is back on, when the drive will spin continuously.

I also need to mention that those sounds are very faint and I only heard them at night in a quiet room, but it's still there and I would like to know why.

Here are some facts:

1. It's only happening while the laptop is on battery.
2. It's staring when the computer turns off the display, regardless of the HDD Power Options.
3. It actually turns on the HDD, if previously was in an OFF state.

   I have set the Power Options to turn the HDD OFF after 1 minute and the screen after 2 minutes. The system turned off the HDD after 1 minute as expected, but then woke it up (when screen turns off) to make those specific sounds I have mentioned.
4. I have played with the APM settings from "Crystal Disk Info" but nothing seems to happen when either on or off.

Questions:

I don't know if this is really an issue with the HDD itself or some driver/software issue or if it's really an issue at all, but I would like to know what's going on.

I've read about head parking, and while the 'click' does sound like moving the head in a certain direction, I think it would be pointless to park and unpark the head until the screen is on.

I have also read about some tasks scheduled to defrag HDD's when the system is idle but this does not seem to be the case either since it's last occurrence was 1 week ago. Some other task scheduled at idle times perhaps?

While other threads exist on the same topic, none of them really answered any questions.

Looking at the SMART values, I see a RAW value of 77263 for Start_Stop_Count. The value seems to be quite high, despite the fact that I almost never keep my laptop unplugged. Is this value related to those sounds? Now I'm thinking it's occurring in other circumstances as well. I'm starting to get worried. I already backed up all the important data, but I would hate to lose this drive.

Comment: Hello. I'd check the SMART. What does crystaldiskinfo say? Post a screenshot of it.

Comment: I have added the SMART values in the post. As mentioned in the Edit1, Start_Stop_Count looks a little high, but I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Your hard drive numbers don't match anything...is it perhaps a Green WD drive? They have quite an aggressive parking behavior, and your LOAD CYCLE count shows exactly that. Try using the WD hack for parking: https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/hacking-wd-greens-and-reds-with-wdidle3-exe.18171/

Comment: It's an WD Blue Drive. I can see the high Load Cycle count values and I'm guessing it's designed this aggressively because it's a laptop drive and lots of movement is expected. What I don't understand is why park and unpark, over and over again, in a 2 second frame and why only when the screen is off! I'm not really against parking aggressively, but in my case it sounds like it can't park and retries again and again. Thank you for a good read, the OP said to use that tool ONLY with WD Green drives so I won't try it.

Comment: @SergiuElmi The click being heard is normal and expected behavior - it occurs from the heads reaching the edge of the platters and resetting; it's nothing to be concerned about.  If it was an extremely loud or harsh clicking sound, that would indicate a damaged HDD, but that's not what you're describing

Comment: From this (post#4) : https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/excessive-head-parking-on-internal-hdd.2137657/   I can confirm that wdidle3 works on WD blue drives. It definitely has no chance of breaking anything afaik.